# <built-in function __import__> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, elementtree

When I am trying to `import` ElementTree as mentioned in [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), I am getting the following error.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'deepcopy'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Pycharm/PycharmProjects/untitled/temp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
  File "C:\Users\chilukuri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1654, in <module>
    from _elementtree import *
SystemError: <built-in function __import__> returned a result with an error set
```

from this line

```
File "C:\Users\chilukuri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1654, in <module>
        from _elementtree import
```

I understand that, it is failing on importing * from `_elementtree`

I tried searching for this *_elementtree* in whole Python36-32 directory, but cannot find it, is it the reason?

Comment: If you named a file `copy.py`, pick a different name. (Also, consider filing a bug report, because `_elementtree` should have handled that better.)

Comment: @user2357112 renaming "copy.py", a file I created in my project,  fixed the issue! Thank you.